# Rails scaffolding for JSON only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, scaffolding

When I use `rails g scaffold Model key:string value:string` command it creates both controller and views (erb, scss, js). How can I generate only controller which will respond with only JSON format.

Comment: How can I do this? If I skip assets controller will be for JSON only (as I know it will have HTML also)?

Answer (score 13):

#### Use API flag in Rails 5+

Without having to modify configuration:

```
rails g scaffold TestLink --api
```

Pro tip: Use the --pretend flag to see what will be created before running:

```
rails g scaffold TestLink --api --pretend
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a project setup as a normal rails app, you can make the generators api only by setting it up in `config/application.rb`.

```rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.api_only = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the Rails controller generated by the scaffold you can add a new file: `lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`. It might be helpful to copy the [template from the Rails source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb) as a starting point. From there you can edit each of the actions to end with `render json`, for example:

```
# GET <%= route_url %>
def index
  @<%= plural_table_name %> = <%= orm_class.all(class_name) %>
  render json: @<%= plural_table_name %>.to_json
end
```

To prevent asset/view files from being generated, add this to your `config/application.rb` file:

```
module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # comments and config
    # ...
    config.generators do |g|
      g.stylesheets false
      g.javascripts false
      g.helper false
      g.views false
    end
  end
end
```